# HTLM5 Pattern for PAK Phone Number Format

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am trying to make a html5 pattern for Pakistan Phone Number Format which is as follows:

```
03xx-xxxxxxx
```

Where `x` represents a number. Uptil now I have developed this regex:

```
/03[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}/
```

What I am trying now is to make sure that the next 7 digits after the hyphen:

1. Aren't the same numbers like: `1111111`
2. Aren't in a continuous manner like: `1234567`
3. Aren't in a reverse manner like: `7654321`

I have no idea how to put these checks in the regex. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question says that you want it for HTML5; but you have used the javascript tag...

Comment: "Let's use a regex" is not the first thing that comes to mind here.

Comment: When you say "Doesn't need to be" do you mean "Is not"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633979/10511266 might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `HTML5` Pattern For pakistani Mobile Numbers

```
<input type="text" pattern="03[0-9]{2}-(?!1234567)(?!1111111)(?!7654321)[0-9]{7}" name="mobile_number" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great at regex but I can't think of anyway of doing the second and third conditions without disallowing every combination of numbers in a continuous manner. If you don't mind really ugly regex then this would work for solving all three rules.

```
03[0-9]{2}-(?!0123456)(?!1234567)(?!2345678)(?!3456789)(?!4567890)(?!0987654)(?!9876543)(?!8765432)(?!7654321)(?!6543210)([0-9])(?!\1{6})[0-9]{6}
```

Test [here](http://regex101.com/r/iG0qM1/1).

Now if you can find another way to test the second two conditions then the regex is much simpler.

```
03[0-9]{2}-([0-9])(?!\1{6})[0-9]{6}
```

Test [here](http://regex101.com/r/iG0qM1/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- Pakistani phone number format: +923101234567 pattern="[\+]\d{2}\d{10}"-->
    <!-- For Reg Expression : pattern : [\\+]\\d{2}\\d{10} -->
    <form>
      <label for="country_code">Pak Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone_no" name="phone_no" pattern="[\+]\d{2}\d{10}" title="ex: +923101234567"><br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```